# Объединить значения выборки

Tags: php

Есть массив.
В массиве мы получаем несколько значений. 
Например:
amount=>0.12
amount=>0.1212
amount=>1.12
amount=>3

Как сделать чтобы amount выдала общую сумму?
То есть оплюсовать значения именно ключа amount

Comment: Использовать [array_sum()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-sum.php). Если данные разбиты по подмассивам, то нужно использовать `foreach` / `array_map`

Comment: Та не.) 
Я сделал проще. 
while($rowr = mysql_fetch_array($vibor)){
$amount += $rowr['amount'];
}

Comment: @RattleSneyk, "решение" к вопросу слабое отношение имеет :) Или наоборот - вопрос не для того решения задан. Но вообще, и в mysql есть функция `sum()`:

    select sum(`amount`) from `table` where ...